# syntax error in constraint clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

I don't know what am doing wrong but my constraint clause is not working

```
ALTER TABLE Employee 
ADD CONSTRAINT CheckSalary CHECK (Salary > 0);
//entitesin my table
EMPID   
EMPNAME
EMPDOB  
EMPRGENDER  
EMPCONTACT  
EMPADDRESS  
EMPSSN  
EMPSTATUS   
EMPLOYMENTID    
EMPEMAIL    
SALARY
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: "is not working" is not helpful. What is the error?

Comment: What error are you getting? Does the table have records already? If so, have you confirmed that all existing records have a salary value?

Comment: ...does the table in fact have a column called Salary?

Comment: no i havent placed an records in the table its blank @Declan_K  the error is give me in access is syntax error in constraint clause

Comment: EMPID EMPNAME EMPDOB EMPRGENDER EMPCONTACT EMPADDRESS EMPSSN EMPSTATUS EMPLOYMENTID EMPEMAIL SALARY  these are the entites in my table

Comment: @Mystro you should post the exact error message you are getting

Comment: The exact error message for this one is just *"Syntax error in CONSTRAINT clause."*  It doesn't give you any more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS-Acess does not support `CHECK` constaints, instead it uses what it calls "Validation Rules".

See [MSDN](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-validation-rule-to-validate-data-in-a-field-HA010096312.aspx) for more info.

Comment: oh ok  so i just have to make the validation rule  Salary > 0

Answer (score 2):

Check constraints are only supported in Access DDL when executed from ADO.

Here is an Immediate window example ...

```vb
strSql = "ALTER TABLE Employee " & vbCrLf & _
"ADD CONSTRAINT CheckSalary CHECK (Salary > 0);"
? strSql
ALTER TABLE Employee 
ADD CONSTRAINT CheckSalary CHECK (Salary > 0);
' CurrentDb is a DAO object, so this will throw
' error 3289, "Syntax error in CONSTRAINT clause."
CurrentDb.Execute strSql
' CurrentProject.Connection is an ADO object,
' so this works ...
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql
```

Note if you were trying to execute that statement from the query designer, it would also fail because the query designer uses DAO.

So you can have a `CHECK` constraint if you want one, but setting a Validation Rule for `Salary` might be easier.  Either way, you may also want to prohibit Nulls from `Salary`.

Comment: You can do it from the Immediate window (Ctrl+g to go there) as in my answer.  Or you could write a VBA procedure to do the same, and run the procedure.  Or from outside an Access application session, you could write VBScript to connect to the Access db file with ADO and execute the `ALTER TABLE` statement from there.